# How to prove that $f(x)=x+\frac{1}{x}$ is not cyclic?

Tags: functions, solution-verification

Let $f(x)=x+\frac{1}{x}$ and define a cyclic function as one where $f(f(...f(x)...))=x$.

How do prove that $f(x)$ is not cyclic?

What I tried was to calculate the first composition:

$f(f(x))=x+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x+\frac{1}{x}}=\frac{x^4+3x^2+1}{x^3+x}$

Intuitively, I feel that this is clearly not going to simplify down to $x$, but how can I prove this beyond reasonable doubt?

Comment: For positive $x$, $f(x)>x$.

Comment: $f(f(x))=x$ is equivalent to $2x^2+1=0$, which has two complex solutions. I suppose that we have $f\colon \Bbb R\rightarrow \Bbb R$ ? Should it hold for *all* $x\in \Bbb R$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: for positive $x$
$$
f(x) > x
$$

Answer (score 3):

Note that $ f(\frac{1}{x})=f(x) $, then $f$ is not injective.

If $f^n(x)=x, \ n\geq2, $ for all $x$, then $f$ is injective, which is a contradiction.